# Change jupyter notebook server password

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I would like to change my jupyter notebook server's password to something else. I see on Jupyter's documentation (http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public_server.html) how to prepare a password for ostensibly a new server but not how to change an existing one.

Can I simply:

1. Generate a new SHA hash for a password as the documentation above specifies
2. Replace the password in the PWDFILE environment variable (located in jupyter_notebook_config.py)
3. Restart the jupyter server

Basically, I'm asking because I don't want to confuse and/or mess up the authentication system by just changing things.

Comment: I'm not sure where environment variables come into it, but yes, the process for changing the password should be the same as for setting it in the first place. Jupyter is just hashing the password you enter and comparing it against the value loaded from the config file.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Do you mind posting that as an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

The process to change the password should be just the same as setting it in the first place. Jupyter hashes the password you enter, and compares it with the hash it loaded from the config file. It doesn't copy the hash to any other persistent storage (though it does store it in memory, so you will need to restart the notebook server).

I'm not sure how environment variables are involved - I don't think the instructions use any for the password.

Answer (score 96):

From version 5.0, you can easily change current password with `jupyter notebook password` command.

Comment: This should be an answer, it's straight forward
And if someone is looking for how to change password with jupyter-lab, then in fact the same command can be used.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to restart `jupyter notebook` for it to take.

Comment: If you are moving to lab.  `jupyter lab password` also works

Answer (score 11):

**Note** :  I tested it on windows environment.

> Start -> Anaconda Powershell Prompt

It will display you the prompt like below:

> (base) PS C:\yourName >

Enter below command :

> (base) PS C:\yourName > **jupyter notebook password**

It will ask you for new password

Answer (score 9):

Currently its 2022 and the `jupyter notebook password` still works